# How to open gallery intent using Ucrop library in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using the library https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop provided here.

I want to open gallery intent directly when a button is clicked with crop option facility but how do I do it??

Currently, am doing this

```
public void onclickbutton (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        if (checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(this)) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
        }
}
```

in Onactivity result

```
if (requestcode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultcode == RESULT_OK) 
        {
        uri = data.getData();
        UCrop.of(uri, uri)
                .withAspectRatio(16, 9)
                .withMaxResultSize(500, 500)
                .start(this);
    }
```

Again in onactivity result

```
 if (resultcode == RESULT_OK && requestcode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
            final Uri resultUri = UCrop.getOutput(data);
            Toast.makeText(this, resultUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (resultcode == UCrop.RESULT_ERROR) {
            final Throwable cropError = UCrop.getError(data);
        }
```

Please help me where I am going wrong..

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Onactivity result
you are passing same uri you must pass source uri and destination uri. like shown below

```
  UCrop.of(sourceUri, destinationUri)
       .withAspectRatio(16, 9) 
       .withMaxResultSize(maxWidth, maxHeight)
       .start(context);
```

Comment: what should be the destination Uri??

Comment: Create a new file in Gallery and pass that file path Uri as destinationUri. File extension should be png or jpg.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and let me know how to do it?